# SQL queries: Possible to search two columns at once with the same query parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-like

I have a search function that searches the database for words matching the query_string. Currently you can either search by street OR by locality, USRN etc., if you type in both the street and the locality, for example, it does not find anything because the street and locality are two separate columns of the same table. If, however, I type in either one of those, the query returns a list of relevant suggestions. How can I make it so that one doesn't cancel out the other?

Thanks

here is my query:

```
SELECT USRN,
       RTRIM(SD)+', '+RTRIM(NT.TOWN_NAME) AS FEATURE_NAME,
       KEYWORDS = CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15))+' '+RTRIM(SD)+''+RTRIM(NL.LOCALITY_NAME)+' '+RTRIM(NT.TOWN_NAME)+''+RTRIM(NA.AUTHORITY_NAME)
FROM NS
     INNER JOIN NT ON NT.TOWN_UID = NS.TOWN_UID
     INNER JOIN NL ON NL.LOCALITY_UID = NS.LOCALITY_UID
     INNER JOIN NA ON NA.AUTHORITY_UID = NS.AUTHORITY_UID
WHERE CAST(USRN AS VARCHAR(15))+' '+RTRIM(SD)+' '+RTRIM(NL.LOCALITY_NAME)+' '+RTRIM(NT.TOWN_NAME)+''+RTRIM(NA.AUTHORITY_NAME) LIKE '%'+@SEARCH_STRING+'%';
```

EDIT: After some thought, I think it might be possible by splitting the query_string into single words and then applying the `LIKE` Statement on each of those split words dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, the DBMS is Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: Do you really have values from all those columns (usrn, descriptor, town_name, authority_name) in your search string apart from the ones you are asking about?

Comment: Yes there are values in all of those columns. I didn't mention them for simplicity

Comment: I didn't ask if there are values in the columns, I asked if values _from_ those columns are part of the search string. That is, is usrn, descriptior etc something that is mandatory to include when searching?

Comment: Yes, the user needs to be able to search by USRN (a number representing each street), street descriptor (street name), locality and town name. Right now, the user can only type one of those, if he types in a combination of them, the search result returns nothing. The user ideally needs to be able to type in one, or a combination of those.

Comment: I think your main problem here is that your `@SEARCH_STRING` parameter can contain several values, you need to have one parameter per column so this is more of a client coding issue and about changing the user interface. If you change that the query becomes much simpler.

Comment: For example; If a user enters USRN and Town Name - what value do you get in the @SEARCH_STRING?

Comment: @ICospac SEARCH_STRING is what the user has typed in. If the user types in the USRN followed by the Town Name, SEARCH_STRING  will be both the USRN and Town Name. I have bootstrap typeahead which displays suggestions from the database as the user types. If I type in the USRN followed by the Town Name, the typeahead returns nothing because they belong to different columns in the database. If however I type either of those without the other, the typeahead will suggest the relevant street/Town Name and locality.

Comment: @ICospac I was thinking there might be a way around this by splitting the query_string into single words and then using each individual word as a String_query as opposed to using the whole string. I don't know how to do that though.

Comment: I see, there is only one input field... if you use SQL 2016+ there is a built in function: STRING_SPLIT.  Otherwise you can find variety of functions here: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will help you. Using STRING_SPLIT with CROSS APPLY you can achieve the result.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(USRN Varchar(50), STREET_DESCRIPTOR varchar(50), LOCALITY_NAME VARCHAR(50), TOWN_NAME VARCHAR(50), AUTHORITY_NAME VARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @searchString varchar(max) = '456 eiusmod dolore'

INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES('Lorem', '123 ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'),
('consectetur', '123 do', 'ut', 'magna', 'ad'),
('adipiscing', '456 eiusmod', 'labore', 'aliqua', 'minim'),
('elit', '789 tempor', 'et', 'Ut', 'veniam'),
('sed', '234 incididunt', 'dolore', 'enim', 'quis')

SELECT DISTINCT USRN,STREET_DESCRIPTOR,LOCALITY_NAME, TOWN_NAME,AUTHORITY_NAME
FROM #TempTable T
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@searchString, ' ')
) R
WHERE T.USRN LIKE '%'+R.value+'%' OR  
      T.STREET_DESCRIPTOR LIKE '%'+R.value+'%' OR  
      T.LOCALITY_NAME LIKE '%'+R.value+'%' OR  
      T.TOWN_NAME LIKE '%'+R.value+'%' OR  
      T.AUTHORITY_NAME LIKE '%'+R.value+'%'

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: Thanks, STRING_SPLIT wouldn't work for me, but I managed to find a workaround that is similar to this